# Issues Installing PHPword

Tags: php, json

I've been trying to install PHPWord for the last 4 hours and have had no luck. I've tried all methods of installation including composer as well as downloading the folder itself. Whenever I run the php file, it always returns me the error "Fatal error: Class 'PhpWord' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-world.php on line 9" Also, it seems that whenever I attached the phpoffice/phpword in the composer.json file, it kept on giving me an installation error saying no version specified. BTW, I am running these files on a cloud hosting website (C9.io).

I've attached my composer.json as well as the hello_world.php

Any help is much appreciated.

hello_world.php

```
<?php
require_once('PHPWord-master/Autoloader.php');
\PhpOffice\PhpWord\Autoloader::register();

//use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
//use PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font;
// Creating the new document...
$phpWord = new PhpWord();

/* Note: any element you append to a document must reside inside of a Section. */


Note: it's possible to customize font style of the Text element you add in     three ways:
- inline;
- using named font style (new font style object will be implicitly created);
- using explicitly created font style object. */
// Adding Text element with font customized inline...
$section->addText(
htmlspecialchars(
'"Great achievement is usually born of great sacrifice, '
. 'and is never the result of selfishness." '
. '(Napoleon Hill)'
),
array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10)
);

// Adding Text element with font customized using named font style...
$fontStyleName = 'oneUserDefinedStyle';
$phpWord->addFontStyle(
$fontStyleName,
array('name' => 'Tahoma', 'size' => 10, 'color' => '1B2232', 'bold' => true)
);
$section->addText(
htmlspecialchars(
'"The greatest accomplishment is not in never falling, '
. 'but in rising again after you fall." '
. '(Vince Lombardi)'
),
$fontStyleName
);

// Adding Text element with font customized using explicitly created font      style object...
$fontStyle = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\Style\Font();
$fontStyle->setBold(true);
$fontStyle->setName('Tahoma');
$fontStyle->setSize(13);
$myTextElement = $section->addText(
htmlspecialchars('"Believe you can and you\'re halfway there." (Theodor    Roosevelt)')
);
$myTextElement->setFontStyle($fontStyle);

// Saving the document as OOXML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.docx');

// Saving the document as ODF file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'ODText');
 $objWriter->save('helloWorld.odt');

// Saving the document as HTML file...
$objWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($phpWord, 'HTML');
$objWriter->save('helloWorld.html');

/* Note: we skip RTF, because it's not XML-based and requires a different     example. /
/ Note: we skip PDF, because "HTML-to-PDF" approach is used to create PDF documents. */
?>
```

This is the composer.json require part

```
"require": 
{
"php": ">=5.3.3",
"ext-xml": "*",
"phpoffice/phpword":"dev-master"
},
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like it installed properly since you're getting past the autoloader statements.

The issue is that `PhpWord` is not the class, it would be `\PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord` since it's namespaced.

So you can try:

```
$phpWord = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
```

or add the `use` statement back towards the top of the script which is commented out:

```
use PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord;
```

This will allow you to call the class as `PhpWord` instead of the fully namespaced version.

EDIT:

Try this:

From the command line (you've probably already done this):

```
composer require phpoffice/phpword
```

Create file test.php with contents:

```
<?php

require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$phpword = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
$section = $phpword->addSection();

$section->addText("Hello World!");

$phpword->save('./hello.docx', 'Word2007');
```

That should work.

Comment: When I tried both of those, it returned the same error: Fatal error: Class 'PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord' not found in /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-world.php on line 9

Comment: ok so now it ran but when I ran it the page was simply blank (no error however). I see that it is creating a new doc, but how do I get it to display the data as a doc file on the page? And not have it create a new vendor subsection each time the php file is run?

Comment: And it seems that whenever I call a function such as getDocInfo(); or addFontStyle(); it gives me the error Fatal error: Call to a member function ______ on a non-object

Comment: Call to member function on a non-object would indicate you are using the wrong variable or it is no longer an object and is scalar (string or integer).  As to having the doc show on the page, try `header('Content-type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'); $phpword->save('php://output'); exit;`

Comment: but it is saying that the $phpword is a non-object, so how can I do all of the other functions if it is saying that the $phpword itself is a non object?

Comment: Variables are case sensitive.  Make sure they match in case.